# No sé cómo crear un evento con jquery al hacer click en una imagen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ando con un pequeño problema.Tengo una imagen en una de mis páginas, y necesito que al hacer click en esa imagen, mi js mande la palabra "down" a otra página (llamada buscando.php). Intenté hacerlo pero se ve que no sé escribir bien la sintaxis. Les dejo mi código (cabe recalcar que el js ya está añadido en la página y que tengo todo lo otro funcional)

`<img id ="down" src="../4.imagenes/down.png" width="20" height="20">`

js

```
inicio();
function inicio() {
    resultados();
}

<!---Lean donde dice down-------->

function resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio,down){
$.ajax({
   url : 'buscando.php',
     type : 'POST',
     datatype :'html',
   data : {
         pais: pais,
                 marca : marca,
                 categoria : categoria,
                 precio : precio,
                 down : down
     },
})

.done(function(resultado) {
    $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
})

}


function busqueda(){
    var pais=$("#paises").val();
    var marca=$("#marca").val();
    var categoria=$("#categoria").val();
    var precio=$("#precio").val();
    var down= <!---No sé qué escribir aquí--->

    resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio,down);
}


$(document).on('change','#paises', function() {
     busqueda();
});

<!---No sé de qué forma debo escribir aquí para que al hacer click en #down vaya a la funcion búsqueda---->
```

Comment: la idea es que al hacer click en la imagen, dependiendo del nombre de esta, el buscador tenga cierta reacción. Pero no sé cómo sacar el id y luego el nombre

Comment: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/jquery/ te ayudará :)

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar una función al hacer click en un elemento es similar a como lo tienes al final de tu script:

```
$(document).on('click','#down', function() {
     busqueda();
});
```

Uso el id de la imagen que has puesto al principio del código.

Para enviar el texto "down" la función busqueda() te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
function busqueda(){
    var pais=$("#paises").val();
    var marca=$("#marca").val();
    var categoria=$("#categoria").val();
    var precio=$("#precio").val();
    var down= "down";

    resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio,down);
}
```

Si realmente quieres que sirva para varias imágenes (o elementos) puedes usar una clase común a todos los elementos (.busqueda - por poner un ejemplo) y luego un elemento data en que que poner el texto que quieras para cada imagen.

El código quedaría así:

```
<img id ="down" src="../4.imagenes/down.png" width="20" height="20" class="busqueda" data-text="down">

$(document).on("click",".busqueda", function() {
     var texto=$(this).data("texto")
     busqueda(texto);
});

function busqueda(texto){
     var pais=$("#paises").val();
     var marca=$("#marca").val();
     var categoria=$("#categoria").val();
     var precio=$("#precio").val();
     var down= texto;       
     resultados(pais,marca,categoria,precio,down);
}
```